# How can I make a sprite-sheet-based animation system?

Tags: java, animation, spritesheet

I want to make animations based on a sprite sheet, but I'm stuck implementing it.

The key things I need my code to do are:

- Play through a set of images once (e.g. a jump animation)
- Loop through a set of images continuously (e.g. a walking animation)
- Change an animation's speed

How can I implement such a system?

Answer (score 19):

The way I do 2D animations is as follows:

## Sprite Retrieval Class

This class can either load an image file or it can load a sprite from a sprite sheet.
It's very self explanatory.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Sprite {

    private static BufferedImage spriteSheet;
    private static final int TILE_SIZE = 32;

    public static BufferedImage loadSprite(String file) {

        BufferedImage sprite = null;

        try {
            sprite = ImageIO.read(new File("res/" + file + ".png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return sprite;
    }

    public static BufferedImage getSprite(int xGrid, int yGrid) {

        if (spriteSheet == null) {
            spriteSheet = loadSprite("AnimationSpriteSheet");
        }

        return spriteSheet.getSubimage(xGrid * TILE_SIZE, yGrid * TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE);
    }

}
```

## Animation Class

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Animation {

    private int frameCount;                 // Counts ticks for change
    private int frameDelay;                 // frame delay 1-12 (You will have to play around with this)
    private int currentFrame;               // animations current frame
    private int animationDirection;         // animation direction (i.e counting forward or backward)
    private int totalFrames;                // total amount of frames for your animation

    private boolean stopped;                // has animations stopped

    private List<Frame> frames = new ArrayList<Frame>();    // Arraylist of frames 

    public Animation(BufferedImage[] frames, int frameDelay) {
        this.frameDelay = frameDelay;
        this.stopped = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < frames.length; i++) {
            addFrame(frames[i], frameDelay);
        }

        this.frameCount = 0;
        this.frameDelay = frameDelay;
        this.currentFrame = 0;
        this.animationDirection = 1;
        this.totalFrames = this.frames.size();

    }

    public void start() {
        if (!stopped) {
            return;
        }

        if (frames.size() == 0) {
            return;
        }

        stopped = false;
    }

    public void stop() {
        if (frames.size() == 0) {
            return;
        }

        stopped = true;
    }

    public void restart() {
        if (frames.size() == 0) {
            return;
        }

        stopped = false;
        currentFrame = 0;
    }

    public void reset() {
        this.stopped = true;
        this.frameCount = 0;
        this.currentFrame = 0;
    }

    private void addFrame(BufferedImage frame, int duration) {
        if (duration <= 0) {
            System.err.println("Invalid duration: " + duration);
            throw new RuntimeException("Invalid duration: " + duration);
        }

        frames.add(new Frame(frame, duration));
        currentFrame = 0;
    }

    public BufferedImage getSprite() {
        return frames.get(currentFrame).getFrame();
    }

    public void update() {
        if (!stopped) {
            frameCount++;

            if (frameCount > frameDelay) {
                frameCount = 0;
                currentFrame += animationDirection;

                if (currentFrame > totalFrames - 1) {
                    currentFrame = 0;
                }
                else if (currentFrame < 0) {
                    currentFrame = totalFrames - 1;
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

The animation class has start, stop, restart and reset to control the animation. You could easily add a boolean to test whether it should loop or not. I will not add this for you.

## Frame Class

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class Frame {

    private BufferedImage frame;
    private int duration;

    public Frame(BufferedImage frame, int duration) {
        this.frame = frame;
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public BufferedImage getFrame() {
        return frame;
    }

    public void setFrame(BufferedImage frame) {
        this.frame = frame;
    }

    public int getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setDuration(int duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

}
```

The Frame class holds an image and a duration associated with that image.

## Implementation

The way I implement the animation is as follows:

**Player.java**

```
// Images for each animation
private BufferedImage[] walkingLeft = {Sprite.getSprite(0, 1), Sprite.getSprite(2, 1}; // Gets the upper left images of my sprite sheet
private BufferedImage[] walkingRight = {Sprite.getSprite(0, 2), Sprite.getSprite(2, 2};
private BufferedImage[] standing = {Sprite.getSprite(1, 0)};

// These are animation states
private Animation walkLeft = new Animation(walkingLeft, 10);
private Animation walkRight = new Animation(walkingRight, 10);
private Animation standing = new Animation(standing, 10);

// This is the actual animation
private Animation animation = standing;
```

In your update or tick method you will have:

```
animation.update();
```

In your render or draw method you will have:

```
g.drawImage(animation.getSprite(), x, y, null);
```

Lets say you have implemented MouseListener

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    animation = walkLeft;
    animation.start();
}

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    animation.stop();
    animation.reset();
    animation = standing;
}
```

## Closing Notes

Here is a screen shot of the layout of a sprite sheet.

[image]

Each tile is 32 x 32 pixels.

Normally I wouldn't write this much code. However, I remember when I was struggling to figure this out and it annoyed the shit out of me... So here you go!

Good luck and I hope you can refactor it to suit your needs :)