# animation runs only onces

Tags: java, spritesheet

I found this tutorial on sprite sheets that works great.
[How can I make a sprite-sheet-based animation system?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/53705/managing-sprite-sheets-for-animation)

I am not sure how I could modify it, so that it loops through just once. My thought was to add an if statement in the update method. This way I could stop the animation, but I am unable to figure out what to put in the if statement.

```
public void update() {
    if (!stopped) {
        frameCount++;

        if (frameCount > frameDelay) {
            frameCount = 0;
            currentFrame += animationDirection;

            if (currentFrame > totalFrames - 1) {
                currentFrame = 0; 
               if(){
                   stopped = true;
                }
            }
            else if (currentFrame < 0) {
                currentFrame = totalFrames - 1;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: duplicate: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/46756/game-loop-how-to-check-for-conditions-once-do-something-then-not-do-it-again

Comment: " if()" IF WHAT?

Comment: @Sidar - "...but unable to figure it out what to put in if statment."

Comment: @DMan yes but I was hoping he would come up with it himself

Answer (score 1):

I answered that post you are referring to... You need to create a Boolean like so:

```
private boolean loop;
```

And replace

```
If (currentFrame > totalFrames - 1)
```

With

```
   If (currentFrame > totalFrames - 1 && loop)
```

I'm on my phone at the moment. However I don't see why it wouldn't work.

You will need to set the Boolean to either true or false... You can easily do this in the constructor.

Basically it is saying if the current frame number is greater than total frames - 1 (total frame count) and loop = true, then make current frame = to 0 so the animation will restart...

Understand?

Good luck

Comment: i tried it but it is not working.

Comment: Ok lol... Leave it with me and when I get home from work ill test it for you and update my post :)

Comment: why is this close?

Answer (score 0):

Add a boolean `loop` somewhere in the Animation class, then check if it's `false`.

Comment: like this? <br/>
 'boolean loop;
    if(!loop){
    stopped = true;
    }' why its not tell me type?

Comment: You'll have to set `loop` somewhere (perhaps in the constructor) to `false` or `true`.

Comment: ah ok thanks man. just last question variable loop will be true if a animation you i want it to go for every. and false if i want animation to stop. how does java hows which animation is for ever and which is only onces. do just use 'totalFrame' variable to see which animation is being used?

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, the `loop` variable is what determines if it goes forever or not.

Comment: yes, i can not set 'loop' in constructor to true or false right. i would need some kind of test which will tell 'loop' if its true of false. i was just confused on how to do it. do i use 'totalFrames' variable to test it?

Comment: Yes you can... create `loop` in the class, ask for it in the constructor, set its value, and use it to test looping.

Comment: I am not trying to be difficult but i always found working with  images very difficult. i set up if statment in constructor, if totalFrames doesnt equal 4 than set loop to true. otherwise set loop to false. but wasnt seem to be working. 4 is the number of frames that i want to loop though onces

Comment: I mean something like this: http://pastebin.com/nFekA7h0

Comment: i made the changes but still it looping for ever. may be iam calling my animation wrong? but i dont think so. http://pastebin.com/tJ9hp2UT .