# Background with small, randomly moved elements in LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm looking to implement a 'dynamic' background (meaning, with objects moving randomly) in my libgdx game, something **similar to what you can see in this video** (from the Google Play game 'Finger Dodge'):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zf8mpqf0jGc

In the above example, the background has a **bunch of moving squares and triangles (and some blinks) that move randomly, independently from each other**. So, what exactly should be the best approach to get something like that? I'm guessing that those background elements aren't just a bunch of single, independent textures that all get rendered at the same time with a random direction, because that would seem a bit TOO much stuff to render... Or am i wrong and that's what it might be?

**So, is there any way to consistently and efficiently achieve this effect in libgdx (or if not, any other way)?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing in the video is just an animated background image , You can try to create your owen using sprite sheet animation techniques ( see [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/53705/how-can-i-make-a-sprite-sheet-based-animation-system) ) take a look here also :

- [Animated background using Libgdx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13324390/animated-background-using-libgdx)

Comment: thank you so much! I honestly had no idea, going to check it out. :)